# #if DEBUG returns true on production server

Tags: asp.net-mvc

We have the following code on the Global.asax of an MVC web application

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        #if DEBUG
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request["debug"]))
        {
            RouteDebug.RouteDebugger.RewriteRoutesForTesting(RouteTable.Routes);
        }                
        #endif
    }
```

the "compilation debug" atribute  set as  "false" in web.config of the production server. 
So the expected behavior is that the above code will never get executed . it works most of the time, but then all of a sudden the app is starting to execute this code. It will continue to do so Until I do an IIS reset.  I can't seem to figure out why all of a sudden our website goes into the debug mode automatically.  any Idea?

Comment: Make sure you do not have `#define DEBUG` in your code. (But if it is only sometimes, then that should not be it ...)

Comment: The only possible answer is that you've compile your app in Debug mode. Take a look at ConfigurationManager to check that.

Comment: Thanks for help guys. The problem is that it doesn't happen all the time. the website seem to be working fine as expected 99 percentage of the time. but out of a blue the the website goes to the debug mode (automatically) and start to execute this code in every further requests.  If I do an IIS reset it will solve the problem and everything is back to normal

Comment: Did you check whether the assembly was compiled as debug mode as requested by Thiago?

Answer (score 5):

The `#if DEBUG` line is a compiler directive and can only be called if the DEBUG constant has been defined manually in the code or specified in the build (which is set up in your project properties.

The web.config compilation value of `debug="true"` is a completely different thing. To determine if that has been set, you can use this instead:

```
var compilation = (CompilationSection)ConfigurationManager
                      .GetSection("system.web/compilation");

if (compilation.Debug)
{
    //Debug is on!
}
```

Comment: This is more than likely the correct answer. When you compile for production, make sure to compile using the "Release" build configuration (which by default, should have the DEBUG constraint set to FALSE)